# Find lines in a file which have two or more ";" symbols

Tags: regex, linux, string, grep

how can i determine lines in a file, which have two or more ";" symbols on one line in linux cmd?

thanks,
Pa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
grep '.*;.*;' filename
```

This will print the lines containing at least 2 `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is enough:

```
grep ';.*;' filename
```